# PasteSpecial not working

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have a sub which looks for values in the SolutionID column that match an array of values in one table, and then copies that over to the other.

However, I'm hitting an error with the `.PasteSpecial` method -

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
Private Sub CopySolutions(ByRef SourceTable As ListObject, ByRef DestinationTable As ListObject, ByRef values() As String)

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i, j As Integer ' Dummy for looping

    '** Loop through all of the ID's to copy... *'
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)

        With SourceTable.DataBodyRange

            For j = 1 To .Rows.Count

                If .Cells(j, 1).Value = values(i) Then

                    .Rows(j).Copy   ' Copy the row in the SourceTable

                    Dim LastRow As Integer

                    LastRow = DestinationTable.Rows.Count   ' Work out the number of rows in the DestinationTable

                    '** Check to see if the last row in the destination table is already empty '*
                    If DestinationTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value <> "" Or LastRow = 0 Then
                        DestinationTable.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True    ' Insert a new row in to the DestinationTable
                        LastRow = LastRow + 1                               ' Increment LastRow to take in to account the newly added row
                    End If

                    DestinationTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(LastRow, 1).Select       ' Select the last row, column 1 in the Destination Table
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                           Operation:=xlNone, _
                                           SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                           Transpose:=False         ' Paste the copied row

                    Exit For    ' Exit the For, there is no need to keep checking for matches

                End If

            Next

        End With

    Next

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Call ErrorOutput("An error occured while copying your selected solutions.")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    WS.Range("Solution").Select ' Reselect the Solution cell range

End Sub
```

Comment: Move `.Rows(j).Copy` just before the line where you paste. Excel has a habit of clearing the clipboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to avoid copy/paste alltogether:

```
Dim rngSrc as Range
'...
Set rngSrc = .Rows(j)
'...

DestinationTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(LastRow, 1). _
         Resize(1, rngSrc.Columns.Count).Value = rngSrc.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SourceTable.DataBodyRange.Rows(j).Copy DestinationTable.DataBodyRange.Range("A" & CStr(lastRow))
```

after you find last row of course. That way you don't have to use `.Select`

Comment: Thanks, that works for copying, but it pastes everything (formulas, etc). I require only the `values`.